# Why completed mile stones creating the same milestone again?

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone

I'm trying to implement Entitlement milestones for our support process. I've created a entitlement process with 3 mile stones. First Response(No Recurrence), Resolution Given(Sequential),Resolved(No Recurrence). All got 2,5,7 mins SLA's respectively. I've added this entitlement to one of a Case record and I can see the milestones in the related list. When I update 'Completion Date' manually for Resolution Given(Sequential) milestone, it creates another milestone again. I'm trying to learn how this works, so haven't used a mile criteria. Can some one explain why the milestones triggering again and again?
[image]

You can see the image which shows the milestone keep adding.

Comment: you might also post this on SFDC Success forum where there are more sysads